# Selecting only one child element in AngularJS with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

So, I had a working function in jQuery but then I decided to use Angular for my application. Just can't find the way so it adds the CSS to only one child element.

Jquery code that was working

```
$('.list-div').on('mouseenter', function(){
    $(this).find('.client-jar').css('opacity','1');
  }).on('mouseleave', function() {
    $(this).find('.client-jar').css('opacity','0');
  });
```

Current html

```
<ul>
        <li ng-repeat="one in ones | orderBy:'-date'">
            <div class="list-div">
                <div class="row jar-div first-jar-div" ng-mouseover="showButton()" ng-mouseleave="hideButton()">
                    <div class="col-xs-7 description-div">
                        <p class="version">{{ one.version }}</p>
                        <p class="date">{{ one.date }}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-5 buttons-div">
                        <div class="list-button client-jar">
                            <a class="list-link" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">create server</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="list-button server-jar">
                            <a class="list-link">Server jar</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

And Current Angular JS

```
$scope.showButton = function(){
    angular.element('.list-div').find('.client-jar').css('opacity','1');
  };

  $scope.hideButton = function(){
    angular.element('.list-div').find('.client-jar').css('opacity','0');
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngMouseenter

```
<button ng-mouseenter="hoverState = true">mouse in mouse out</button>
```

Then use with:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngMouseleave

```
<button ng-mouseenter="hoverState = true" ng-mouseleave="hoverState = false">mouse in mouse out</button>
```

At this point you have a hover over and off flag. You can now pick this flag up with ng-class to set and unset a CSS class which contains your opacity stuff, and any future CSS animations etc etc:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass

```
<button ng-mouseenter="hoverState = true" ng-mouseleave="hoverState = false" ng-class="{'opacity-class':hoverState}">mouse in mouse out</button>
```

No jQuery required, AngularJS is just a totally different way of going about things.

```
<style>
.opacity-class .client-jar{
   opacity:0;
}
</style>
<ul>
        <li ng-repeat="one in ones | orderBy:'-date'">
            <div class="list-div">
                <div class="row jar-div first-jar-div" ng-mouseenter="hoverState = true" ng-mouseleave="hoverState = false" ng-class="{'opacity-class':hoverState}">
                    <div class="col-xs-7 description-div">
                        <p class="version">{{ one.version }}</p>
                        <p class="date">{{ one.date }}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-5 buttons-div">
                        <div class="list-button client-jar">
                            <a class="list-link" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">create server</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="list-button server-jar">
                            <a class="list-link">Server jar</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: But the thing is i want to have "hover" effect on only one element while mouse is on the bigger one. Basically, while mouse is on the .list-div div I want only one small element inside it highlighted.

Comment: @NotAJohnDoe  I added your html syntax to my answer.. from what i can see that would work. Note the <style> tag I added. So on hover off the .jar-div doesn't have the .opacity-class (or whatever you best call it). But with it, the CSS sets .client-jar to opacity 0.

Comment: You're right, I got it now and it's working. Big thanks to you!

Answer (score 0):

```
angular.module('App').directive('listFade', function() {
return function(scope, element) {

    element.bind('mouseover', function(children) {
        // YOUR ANIMATION CODE HERE
    });
    element.bind('mouseout', function(children) {
        // YOUR ANIMATION OUT CODE HERE
    });
  }
})
```

then just add the directive to your ng-repeat markup, list-fade=""

you don't need children but its a easy way to call the children of each element.  This should help you out.  Then get rid of that ng-mouseover showButton();

Answer (score 0):

Updating your code to use inline CSS, would be like this.

```
var element = document.querySelector('.list-div .client-jar');

$scope.showButton = function(){
  angular.element(element).css('opacity','1');
};

$scope.hideButton = function(){
  angular.element(element).css('opacity','0');
};
```

As in AngularJS `.element` documentation, it's said that you need to pass a element.

You can also use `ng-class`, creating a class for opacity:

```
<div class="client-jar" ng-class="{class: expression}"></div>
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass

Or use `ng-show` and `ng-hide` for display control:

```
<div class="client-jar" ng-show="expression"></div>
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow

You could even use `ng-style` for inline css:

```
<div class="client-jar" ng-style="{'opacity': '1'}"></div>
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle

Comment: Doesn't work, nothing happens :|. I know about other ways to change opacity but my problem is that I can't select that children.

Comment: Oh! I've read the AngularJS docs now. `.find()` is said to be limited only to tag names. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Hmm it's still not working for me, but the other answer sold my problem. Thanks anyway :)